# Apply ::-webkit-scrollbar to one specific element

Tags: html, css

Im using the `::-webkit-scrollbar` to overcome problems when a user scrolls the terms and conditions very fast on an Android device. Most of the rest of the project uses [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5). I just want to apply the `::-webkit-scrollbar` property to the terms and conditions div and nowhere else as iScroll is used everywhere else. The html is:

```
<section class="content">
<h1>
    <strong>Terms & conditions</strong>
</h1>

<p>blah blah</p>
....
</section>
```

I thought I could do this in CSS:

```
.content ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px; 
}

.content ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.content ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

But by using the .content prefix, the webkit-scroller is not applied and no scrollbar applies. If I leave out the .content, it works but is then applied to other areas too where I dont want it. Any ideas how to just target one specific element with `::-webkit-scrollbar`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the space between `.content` and `::-webkit`:

```
.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px; 
}
```

Leaving the space in there means you're looking for **children** of `.content` rather than the container itself.

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/g4mnvang/)